# how to click checkbox using xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

**This is the website code for check box that i want to click.**

```
<div class="radio-checkbox-group margin-top-30">
<label for="policy_confirmed" class="icheck-label icheck[vhq2e]"> 
<div class="icheckbox icheck-item icheck[vhq2e] icheck-area-20" style="position: relative;"><input type="checkbox" name="policy_confirmed" id="policy_confirmed" value="1" class="icheck-input icheck[vhq2e]">
</div> I have read and understood the <a href="/en-ca/niv/information/privacy_policy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy and the Terms of Use</a> </label>

</div>
```

**Code i write**

```
wb.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="checkbox" and @id="policy_confirmed"]').click()
```

**Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElementClickInterceptedException          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 wb.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="checkbox" and @id="policy_confirmed"]').click()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\test_environment\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:80, in WebElement.click(self)
     78 def click(self):
     79     """Clicks the element."""
---> 80     self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\test_environment\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:633, in WebElement._execute(self, command, params)
    631     params = {}
    632 params['id'] = self._id
--> 633 return self._parent.execute(command, params)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\test_environment\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:321, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320 if response:
--> 321     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322     response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323         response.get('value', None))
    324     return response

File ~\anaconda3\envs\test_environment\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:242, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    240         alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="checkbox" name="policy_confirmed" id="policy_confirmed" value="1" class="icheck-input icheck[ilagf]"> is not clickable at point (51, 472). Other element would receive the click: <div class="icheckbox icheck-item icheck[ilagf] icheck-area-20" style="position: relative;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.125)
```

Any help would be appreciated.
thank you

Comment: `ElementClickInterceptedException` Indicates that a click could not be properly executed because the target element was obscured in some way, means there is another object covering the target element. Try with other locator and add `HTML` source for that element so we can answer you.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. just update the code. could you please review it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to click with javascript, something like this and avoid using find_element_by_xpath. use just find_element with By.XPATH:

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    el = wb.find_element(By.XPATH, '<your_locator>')
    wb.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)
```